# Determine the best-fitting distribution... again!

Tags: distributions, model-selection, assumptions, computational-statistics, recommender-system

I am trying to build a (very simple) recommender system on which statistical model to use, as a learning exercise. It only targets inference (not prediction).

Doing that, it would be nice to isolate a set of best-fitting distributions for the chosen variable, as a part of model assumption verification. Reading on various Q&As on this website [[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22200/45752), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/112349/45752), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/112631/45752)] and R [packages](http://www.biomath.ugent.be/~othas/smooth2/R-Package.html), I understand this to be a most difficult issue.

From answers to other questions, I do understand that no single particular distribution can be isolated, but **it seems to me that a set of best-fitting distributions can be identified. Am I mistaken?**

For example, a (very naive) way would be to sort the kernel density function of the tested variable against a coefficient cutoff obtained through comparison of the targeted distributions kernel density functions, using some kind of pattern recognition algorithm...

And what about the [fitdistrplus R package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=fitdistrplus)?

Can this be done?

Comment: The best fit you can get to any data of $n$ observations is the empirical likelihood that places weight $1/n$ at each of the observed points.  You need to penalize/control complexity somehow for this question to be well posed.